# Apply desktop wallpaper policy on an OU

Tags: group-policy

We need to apply specific background image to all workstations of a specific OU of a department in our organization. I am trying this by using the GPO desktop wallpaper Through the GPMC (server 2008 R2),
But I am not sure about where to exactly create this policy and how to make sure it is applied only for that OU. I am looking for instructions. Should I apply it on the users or desktop OU?

Another question is where to save the image so every workstation will be able to access it? Or the GPO Creation wizard is already makes a copy of it in a public place like in a policy folder under sysvol directory, so this is not a problem.

Finally, how can I grant an access for specific people from the organization to edit this policy?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply Google "set+wallpaper+through+group+policy" should give you plenty of tutorial.
https://www.google.com/#q=set+wallpaper+through+group+policy
http://prajwaldesai.com/deploy-desktop-background-wallpaper-using-group-policy/

To answer your question, if you want to apply only to certain OU, right click on that OU and select "Create a GPO in this domain, and link it here", put a name for it, then configure the wallpaper. Wallpaper configuration is under "User Configuration" so you need to apply to user OU.

It depends on where you want to put the image file, either put in SYSVOL, which is shared, or you may push the image to every PC and set the wallpaper to local.

You can grant permission to others thru the "Delegation" tab in GPMC.